# How to manipulate data from file and sort python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a .dat file with this information inside (but the real file with thousans of lines):

```
    n      a (au)  k0    k1 P1   k2 
    1    3.156653   2     3 5   -18 
    2    3.152517   2     5 5   -23 
    3    3.154422   3   -18 5    29 
    4    3.151668   3   -16 5    24 
    5    3.158629   5   -19 5    21 
    6    3.156970   5   -17 5    16 
    7    3.155314   5   -15 5    11 
    8    3.153660   5   -13 5     6 
    9    3.152007   5   -11 5     1 
   10    3.150357   5    -9 5    -4
```

I load the data by:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *

n = array([])
a = array([])
k0 = array([])
k1 = array([])
p1 = array([])
k2 = array([])
p2 = array([])

l = np.loadtxt('pascal.dat', skiprows=1, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5)).T
n=append(n,l[0])
a=append(a,l[1])
k0=append(k0,l[2])
p1=append(p1,l[3])
k1=append(k1,l[4])
p2=append(p2,l[5])
```

I want to use the values of the column  "a(au)" to compute the distance of each element of the "n" column from the a given center, thus:

```
center = 3.15204
for i in range(len(n)):
    distance = abs(center-a[i]))
```

Well, now I want to re-write the .dat file taking into account the value of distance. Therefore, I want to add a new column called "distance" and then I want to sort all the n rows as function of this new parameter, being the smallest (closest to the center) first and so on.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is ```array([])```? What is the function ```append(```?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the pandas library. Read the .dat file in as a dataframe - it's a very powerful tool through which you can manipulate data, add columns, etc.

```
import pandas as pd

with open('../pascal.dat') as f:
    df = pd.Dataframe(f)

center = 3.15

df['distance'] = abs(3.15 - df['a (au)'])
```

Comment: Seconded. This sounds like a job for the pandas DataFrame. It has a sort method too. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html

Comment: `df.sort_values(by = ['distance'])` to be precise.